# Where else is the movement of living entity within the womb is narrated apart from Bhagavata?

Tags: identification-request

[Canto 3 of Bhagavata Purana, chapter 31](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/31) describes the movement of the soul in the womb of a human mother. Is it described in any other purana in greater detail?

Comment: Does the linked question as duplicate as answers your question? If not please edit it and clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The embryology or lifecycle of fetus in the womb as described in Bhagavata Purana is also discussed in other puranas.

For example [**Markandeya Purana**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.188841/page/n107) - Canto 11 - Conversation between father and son ,(Sumati) jada explains how living beings are conceived and born , and mentions the evils of all existence -

And [**Agni Purana**](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n1049) Chapter Three  hundred and sixty nine - Description of absolute dissolution and the process of creation. 
 both are  also discussing the topic. Although not as clear and in detail as Bhagavata Purana.

---

## Agni Purana

> 19-20 The soul after having entered the womb dwells in the foetus . It
>   gets hard in the second month. The limbs grow in the third . Bones
>   skin and flesh (are formed) in the fourth (month). Hair grows in the
>   fifth (month) . Heart is formed in sixth. The soul feels pain in
>   seventh.
>
> 21 Thus (the child)  remains in the womb being covered with the
>   placenta and having hands folded above the head. A eunuch stays in the
>   middle (of the abdomen) , a female (child) on the left side and male
>   (child) on the right side.
>
> 22 The child stays in the womb facing the back (of the mother) . There
>   is o doubt that it ( the child) recognises the person in whose womb it
>   stays.
>
> 23 It knows fully all the incidents of previous life from birth
>   onwards . A person finds great darkness and (experiences) suffering.
>
> 24 In the seventh month it partakes the food eaten by the mother. It
>   becomes extremely restive in the eighth and ninth months.
>
> 25 It suffers when there is coition and physical exercise on the part
>   of the mother . It becomes sick when the mother is sick , moment of
>   agony appearing as if lasting for hundreds of years.
>
> 26 It is tormented by the past deeds and makes a resolutions : "O
>   Brahman  ! After getting out of the womb i will gain the knowledge
>   relating to liberation from this bondage.
>
> 27 Being press down by the wind inside mothers womb , it gets out
>   through the Vagina . It gets afflicted in the first month after birth
>   and feels pain when touched with the hand.

---

## Markandeya Purana

The son spoke -

> 1 " Now human impregnation of women is a seed sown in darkness ;
>   immediately it discharged it sets out from
>
> 2 Naraka or swarga . Dominated thereby two seeds attain firmness , O
>   father ! and next the character of a speck - of a
>
> 3 globule - of a ball of flesh. As there may be minute seed in the
>   ball of flesh , so it i called a germ. So the five limbs up-
>
> 4 grow   according to their parts ; and the minor limb also , the
>   fingers , the eyes and  nose , the mouth and the ears , grow out of
>   the limbs ; similarely the nails and the other features grow out of
>
> 5 them. In the skin is developed the hair of the body  , and
>   afterwards the hair of the head .The womb verily increases
>
> 6 In size equally with it . Just as the cocoa -nut enlarges together
>   with its shell , so it grows in size. the womb is situated with
>
> 7 Its mouth downwards . But at the bottom of the womb the fetus
>   develops  , placing its hands on the either side of the knees and its
>   finger in
>
> 8 front of them ; behind the knees are the eyes and between the knees
>   is the nose ; and the buttocks rest on the heels ; the arms and legs
>   lie outside.
>
> 9    In this way gradually grows human being ,when contained in the
>   womens womb : inn the womb of other
>
> 10 creatures ,  the position of the fetus corresponds to its form.The
>   gastric fluid  renders it firm. It lives on the food and drink taken
>   by its mother .Thus the gestation of a living creature is
>
> 11 meritorious , and constitutes a means of obtaining merit. Also the
>   cord  , which is called as Apyayani , is fixed in its naval and it
>
> 12  becomes fixed in the belly of the women . As women's food and
>   drink penetrate into their womb , the fetus increases in size its body
>   is nourished thereby.
>
> 13 " Numerous matters of its transmigrations occure to its memory ;
>   hence distressed on this side and on that it becomes
>
> 14 dispirited , thinking , ' Never again will I thus act , when once i
>   am delievered from this womb ; assuredly I will so strive
>
> 15 that I do not again undergo conception .' Thus it meditates
>   recollecting the hundreds of pain attending existence , which have
>   been experienced aforetime , and which spring from destiny .
>
> 16 "Afterwards in the course of time the fetus turns round with its
>   face downwards , since it is born in ninth or tenth month
>
> 17 While it is been expelled , it is pained by the wind of the
>   prjapatis ,and  it is expelled wailing , being pained by
>
> 18 heart by its sufferings .And when from the belly , it falls into an
>   intolerable swoon ; and it gains consciousness
>
> 19 when it comes into contact with the air . Thereupon Vishnu's
>   magical power , which effaces consciousness , assails it  ; its soul
>   being stupefied thereby , it loses its knowledge.